# GLMER levene's test significant

Tags: lme4-nlme, assumptions, levenes-test

I am running a `glmer` and I checked for assumptions of normality (plotting QQ plots) and homogeneity of variances using Levene's test.

My variable A is something called a conditional response probability. I.e what is the probability of remembering a word given that another word was remembered amongst a list of 14 words. Which I assume is then a ratio.

```
levene_test(A ~ B*C*D, data=data)
```

is significant, which shows a violation of the assumption.

What is the best way to deal with it in my model?

I used plot(myglmer) to visually explore my variance distribution (see image below).

[image]

The distribution of the residuals of the model hist(residuals(myglmer)) is the following:

[image]

Comment: Any answer would need a lot more details!

Comment: I added an image to try to clarify my issue. What other information shall I specify?

Comment: These don't look like the relevant residuals.  What exactly is your model?  In particular, what family of conditional response distributions are you using?

Comment: I have used this model glmer(A ~ B*C*D + (1|subject), data = data), therefore, I think it is using a family of gaussian distributions. I added a plot of the distribution of the residuals in my data.

Comment: Certainly a Gaussian response distribution is inappropriate.  But to answer your question reliably, we would need to know what your response variable `A` is and how it is measured.

Comment: My variable A is something called a conditional response probability. I.e what is the probability of remembering a word given that another word was remembered amongst a list of 14 words. See: http://memory.psych.upenn.edu/CRP_Tutorial

Comment: It cannot be a probability, because probabilities are unobservable theoretical constructs.  It might be a ratio, such as one count divided by another; or it could be something else.  *This matters,* because how you measure your response is an important determinant of how it can be (appropriately) modeled.

Comment: I see. I guess in this case it would be a ratio, I assume.

Comment: Please add this new information as an edit to the post!

Comment: It should be clear that the model has biased residuals. Either the loss function or the model fit need to be changed to better approximate the data.

Comment: I understand, however, I was unsure how to determine another distribution's model fit. Do you have any indications / documentation?